# column sum in a certain block in a file: can awk do this?

Tags: awk

I want to treat a certain block in a file.
And the job which I want is to sum column in the block.
Is it possible using awk? Or other commander is better?

1. find a str1 ("atoms" in the sample)
2. then start sum the eighth column $7
3. and stop if you find str2 ("bonds" in the sample)

At the moment what I can do is

```
awk 'BEGIN { i=0; sum=0.0;} { if ($9) { print $7; sum+=$7;}} END {printf "total charge is %10.6f", sum}'
```

In this case if there are another values in 9-th column somewhere, it will be mistake.

[sample file w. 1500 line]

```
.... many lines
[ atoms ]
;   nr  type  resi  res  atom  cgnr     charge      mass       ; qtot   
 1   c3     1     2     C    1     0.138400     12.01000 ; qtot 0.138
 2   os     1     2     O    2    -0.436600     16.00000 ; qtot -0.298
 3   c3     1     2    C1    3    -0.093400     12.01000 ; qtot -0.392
 4   c3     1     2    C2    4    -0.076400     12.01000 ; qtot -0.468

[ bonds ]
;   ai     aj funct   r             k
     1      2   1    1.4316e-01    2.5824e+05 ;      C - O
.... many lines are followed
```

Comment: I believe awk can do this.  Give it a try.  If you run into trouble, post your code and we'll help you.   We like to help, but we want you to give it a shot yourself, we're not a code writing service.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Are you using gawk?  It has an extension where the recorder separator can be a regular expression.  It would allow you to grab the lines you're interested in between [atoms] and [bonds].

Comment: I have gawk separately which means I can use gawk though I have never used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this awk script:

```
awk '$0=="[ atoms ]"{go=1}                         # Set flag to start the sum
     go{sum+=$7}                                   # If flag set sum the 8th column
     $0=="[ bonds ]"{go=0}                         # End the sum
     END{printf "total charge is %10.6f\n",sum}    # Print result
' file
```

Comment: I wonder whether I attach a file here. Your script gives 878.546169 though it should be around 1.

Comment: @JoonhoPark With your given example, and your last edit, the result is `total charge is  0.206499`. How can that be around 1?

Comment: @JoonhoPark Please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without it, it's impossible to tell what could go wrong.

Comment: I have change my file and test it but still it gives 877.078190. If I remove the latter parts it gives -0.468000. That's correct. This means that it reads some values elsewhere. go=0 is not working now.

Comment: it looks you used two if-sentence's. 1. Is it short expression of if? 2. three sentences are working on each line? 3. Is there smarter usage for searching such as "pattern match" rather than "whole line match"? Just I had made a mistake to write the whole line like "[ bonds]".

Comment: @JoonhoPark 1. Yes. 2. Yes, 3. Both exists, but given your example matching the whole is what you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180856/discussion-between-joonho-park-and-oliv).